# Create a Craft 3 module which only initializes on certain pages/after certain events

Tags: yii, craftcms

I have created a module which performs an action after a after a user logs in:

```
    Event::on(User::className(), User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, function ($event) {
        $this->moduleService->action();
         });
```

At the moment, the only way I can get this to run is to add the module to the bootstrap entry. As I only need the module to run at one point, it seems inefficient to have it loading on every page.

Is there a way to have the module only initialize on certain pages (e.g. the login page only)?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in adding the module to the bootstrap entry.
In your module init function check the request for initialization on desired pages, e.g.:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
    if ($request->isCpRequest()) {
        // only for control panel requests
    } else if ($request->getIsSiteRequest()) {
        // the front end site was requested
    }
}
```